# Faster processer Weaker graphics card Or Weaker Graphics card faster processor?

Tags: performance, graphics, processor

So we have PC 1 and PC 2.
Which one would say for instance...be better at running a ps2 emulator for example?

PC1 has an Intel Pentium (newest gen) with a cpu of 2.58ghz 
PC2 intel core 3 (4th gen) with a cpu of 2.30 ghz? 
Which should I get?

Comment: Probably the processor in this one specific case, since emulating the PS2 instructions would tend to tax the CPU a lot more than the GPU scanline rasterizer. But this question has very little to do with programming, and still can't hope for more than biased answers.

Comment: Thanks bro, that helps a lot. 
Much love.